# jquery functionality lost when loading more code without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm quite new to Jquery.

I'm creating a php application including a flow of posts containing text, and sometimes video and images in a flexslider plugin. Initially, 3 posts are shown and I have implemented a "Show More"-button using the following code: (based on [this example](http://codelikeaboss.com/ajax-based-load-more-results-with-jquery-mysql-and-php/))

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.showmore', function () {
        $(this).text('Loading...');
        var ele = $(this).parent('li');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'showmore.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
               page: $(this).data('page'), 
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    ele.hide();
                    $(".posts_list").append(response);
                }
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

This is working just fine, loading 3 new posts with each click WITHOUT page refresh. The problem is all instances of the Flexslider plugin, that won't display correctly. The raw code is included fine, but it's like the Jquery functionality is not connected to the newly loaded posts.
I have tried to include the flexslider script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({randomize: true, animation: "fade", });
    });
</script>
```

again in many places, both inside the showmore.php file and in the above Ajax-script.

I've been searching this and other resources without success.
Could anyone shed some light to this? It's probably quite simple.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to call plugin initialization on new relevant added elements inside `$.ajax` success callback. Eg, depending `response` markup: `$(".posts_list").append($(response).find('.flexslider').flexslider(options).end());` `find()` or `filter()`  and where `options` is an object containing all options to pass to plugin

Comment: You mean this part:   $(window).load(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider({randomize: true, animation: "fade", }); });
Where sould I put it, exactly?

Comment: I edited previous comment. Quite unredable but it gives you the idea...

Comment: Amazing, @A.Wolff! Thank you som much. It's working now.